# Excel 2007 VBA to format disabled Activex command button caption

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, activex

I have disabled an Activex command button using the following code:

```
wks1.OLEObjects.Item("cmdTest2").Object.Enabled = False
```

wks1 has been Set as a Worksheet object.  The disabled command button displays the BackColor correctly but the Caption text changes from its ForeColor and Font combination to what appears as medium-gray text with a white drop shadow.  I want to "gray out" the command button when it's disabled so that users receive the visual cue that the button no longer works.

I've checked MSDN for the properties associated with an Activex command button.  I see a Shadow property, but that's for placing a shadow around the exterior of the command button.

Is there any code that I can use to control the formatting of the command button caption when the command button has been disabled using VBA?

Comment: It is not possible to do what you are asking without changing the way command buttons are displayed for your system.  You could do what you want with an image on the button, though.

Comment: Thanks, jbarker2160, for the quick reply. Two questions - 1. What would I have to do to change the way my system displays command buttons, and 2. Does using the image (GREAT IDEA) require the image to be sized with the same dimensions as the command button?

Comment: To change the system would require a lot of hacks to allow the shadow.  The image would not have to be the same size, but the same aspect ratio would make it prettier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through trial and error I happened to discover how the 'Enabled' property for Activex controls works when it is set to 'False.'  The change in state from enabled to disabled changes the control's text (Caption) to a medium-gray color with a white drop shadow.  I haven't found anything that can change this behavior.  IT LOOKS UGLY ON EVERYTHING - EXCEPT - A BackColor OF &H00E0E0E0&!  The RGB equivalent for this hex code is RGB(224,224,224).  When this Light Grey BackColor is applied to the control, the appearance becomes that of sunken text in a greyed-out control - exactly what I was looking for.

I hope this simple fix helps someone else save time in the future!